# opendaylight: how to include a library jar file?

Tags: karaf, opendaylight

I am developing a feature (consisting of bundles) for Opendaylight Carbon.

I want to include a third party jar (libary) in my feature. How can I do this? I don't want to include it as a bundle - just as a jar file library that is linked to my bundle.

I don't want to bundle this third party jar. I just want to include it such that it is resolvable by MY bundle. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot both not "want to include it as a bundle" NOR "want to bundle this third party jar". How / where from do you expect OSGi (Karaf) to load the classes from your third party JAR then?!

But bundling is perhaps more easy than you may think, because the [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/components/bundle-plugin/) (together with [BND](http://bnd.bndtools.org) which it internally uses) basically can do all the hard work for you if you nicely ask it to via [Embed-Dependency](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#embed-dependency-and-export-package).

Comment: I thought bundles were loaded - each in its own classloader -- which means I could not call one bundle's methods directly from another (?)

Comment: yes, bundles are each loaded in their own ClassLoader (but can access classes via Export-Package and Import-Package in MANIFEST.MF). So if you have a third party JAR that originally was not a valid OSGi Bundle (i.e. does not have Export-Package & Co. in its MANIFEST.MF), then your choices are to EITHER "repackage" that third party JAR as a new JAR which is a valid bundle, and Import each stuff from your bundle, OR to embed that non-OSGi 3rd party JAR into your own bundle. HTH?